# Updating the a user profile upon user save

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm following the ['User profile'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) approach to extend my User model, like so:

```
# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

With this approach, I have to explicitly call `user.profile.save()`, which to me feels clunky, as I want the `profile` to give the illusion it is part of the `User` object:

```
# views.py
def some_func(request):
    user = User.objects.create_user('dummy', 'dummy@dummy.com', '12345678')
    user.profile.my_field = 'hello'
    user.save()          # This does not persist the profile object...
    user.profile.save()  # ...this does
```

To remedy this, I've changed `create_user_profile()` to the following, which works:

```
# signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
   profile.save()
```

Numerous examples I've encountered do not use this approach. Are there any caveats to using this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a few. In the following situations the post_save signal would not be fired.

1 If the save method does not successfully save the object (such as when an IntegrityError occurs)

2 When you call `MyModel.objects.update()`

3 When you override the save method and forget to call the superclass method.

4 When your signal receiver hasn't been successfully registered.

In these situations your profile wouldn't be saved.

Comment: aside from item #2, the same caveats are also true for the first approach. Am I correct?

Comment: Well then you are calling save explicitly rather than being dependent on behind the scenes activity. So none of these caveats woud really matter

Comment: But I am not saying post_save is a bad approach, really it's good. My answer was because you asked!!

Answer (score 4):

The better way is to specify a custom user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    custom_field = models.ForeignKey(
        'contracts.Contract'
    )
    ...

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

You have to update the `settings.py` defining the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` property:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```

Comment: Nice. Why do I need `custom_field` as a foreign key? Can't I just define some char field on the custom `User` object?

Comment: Yes you can. This is only example field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom User model like this :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

and then the signals.py file :

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

what the signals.py file does here is to inform you when a new Profile object is created of the User type which you can further use to create forms that update/create the user's profile.

And to make all this work, you need to import the signals.py file in the apps.py file of your app. For example, this is what your apps.py file would look like :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```